# Google Icons - how to get them?

Tags: icons

I'm searching for google icons for my website, but google doesn't provide somewhere their icons to be used.
Does anyone know how to get them?
btw, something I already found is this:
http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/search-128.png

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to use those icons?

Answer (score 0):

http://deployment.googleapps.com/Home/user-resources/google-icons-and-logos

or, a direct download, http://deployment.googleapps.com/Home/user-resources/google-icons-and-logos/google_apps_icons.zip?attredirects=0

as it's a download, I left the link bare so you can see where it comes from

Answer (score 0):

regarding google icons there is a huge new repository coming with the Material Design thing here : https://www.google.com/design/icons